# Python Seaborn lineplot - Smoothing with Hue

Tags: python, seaborn

[image: Seaborn lineplot]I currently have a time-series plot from seaborn that looks like this: It is calculated from a Dataframe, and the hue is relating to labels. I am trying to smooth this out and make a much smoother plot. My questions is, is there a way to do this in seaborn lineplot itself? Or is it a case of smoothing the data for the grouped "hue" and then re-plotting?

Thanks!

A

Comment: [sns.lineplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html#seaborn.lineplot)You can specify the hue in the parameter. I didn't know about `hue_order` and `hue_norm`.

Comment: Hi, Sorry if I didnt explain that. I got the hue parameter specified. The issue is the graph is not smoothed enough... i am wondering if there is a way to smooth this for each "hue" within Seaborn!

Comment: AFAIK, no, seaborn does not include smoothing options. You should smooth the values in your dataframe, then plot the result with seaborn